# Failed to instantiate LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint: No default constructor found

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to migrate from Spring 3.x to Spring 4.x but Spring Security XML file couldn't be loaded properly.

The XML configuration I suppose needs to be changed but I couldn't find the same over the INTERNET. The XML Configuration that worked with Spring 3.x isn't working with 4.0.1.RELEASE.

This is my XML Configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- This is where we configure Spring-Security  -->
    <security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true"  
        entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" disable-url-rewriting="true" >
    <!-- Below URL's will be intercepted by spring security -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/access/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/analytics/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/access/auth/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/access/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/auth/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')"/>

        <!-- Logout Configuration -->
        <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/access/login" logout-url="/access/logout" />

        <!-- Authentication -->
        <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="authenticationFilter" />
        <!-- Concurrent Session -->
        <!-- <security:custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" /> -->

        <security:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"/> <!-- invalid-session-url="/access/session-expired"  -->

    </security:http>

    <!-- Permission Evaluator Configuration -->
    <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
        <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
    </security:global-method-security>

    <bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
        <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Custom Permission Evaluator -->
    <bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="com.space.um.security.CustomPermissionEvaluator"/>

        <!-- Custom filter for username and password. The real customization is done in the customAthenticationManager -->
        <bean id="authenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
            p:sessionAuthenticationStrategy-ref="sas"
            p:authenticationManager-ref="authenticationManager"
            p:authenticationFailureHandler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"
            p:authenticationSuccessHandler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" /> 

        <!-- Custom authentication manager. In order to authenticate, username and password must not be the same -->
        <bean id="authenticationManager" class="com.space.um.security.CustomAuthenticationManager" />

        <!-- We just actually need to set the default failure url here -->
        <bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"
            p:defaultFailureUrl="/access/login?error=true" />

        <!-- We just actually need to set the default target url here -->
        <bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.space.um.security.AuthenticationSuccessHandler"
            p:defaultTargetUrl="/access/welcome" />

        <!-- The AuthenticationEntryPoint is responsible for redirecting the user to a particular page, like a login page,
        whenever the server sends back a response requiring authentication -->
        <!-- See Spring-Security Reference 5.4.1 for more info -->
        <bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"  
           p:loginFormUrl="/access/login"/>

        <!-- Custom Concurrency Manager -->
        <!-- <bean id="concurrencyFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter"
            p:sessionRegistry-ref="sessionRegistry"/> --> <!-- p:expiredUrl="/access/session-expired" -->

        <!-- Custom Concurrency Control Strategy -->
        <bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy" p:maximumSessions="1">
            <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
        </bean>

        <!-- Session Registry Implementation in use -->
        <bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

        <bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
            <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="authenticationEntryPoint"/>
            <property name="accessDeniedHandler" ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="accessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl">
            <property name="errorPage" value="/access/access-denied"/>
        </bean>

       <!-- AccessDecisionManager -->
        <!-- <bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy" p:maximumSessions="1">
            <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
        </bean> -->

        <!-- The tag below has no use but Spring Security needs it to autowire the parent property of 
        org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager. Otherwise we get an error 
        A probable bug. This is still under investigation-->
        <security:authentication-manager/>
</beans>
```

This is the Exception ...

```
May 16, 2015 9:52:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#6bd58dff' of type [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter] while setting constructor argument with key [7]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6bd58dff': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authenticationEntryPoint' while setting bean property 'authenticationEntryPoint'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationEntryPoint' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/space-security.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#6bd58dff' of type [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter] while setting constructor argument with key [7]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6bd58dff': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authenticationEntryPoint' while setting bean property 'authenticationEntryPoint'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationEntryPoint' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/space-security.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6bd58dff': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authenticationEntryPoint' while setting bean property 'authenticationEntryPoint'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationEntryPoint' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/space-security.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationEntryPoint' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/space-security.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2892)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2058)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
    ... 55 more
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [Migrating from Spring Security 3.x to 4.x (XML Configuration)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html)

[Chapter 4.7.5. LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-deprecations-web)

> The LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint default constructor and the
>   setLoginFormUrl method was removed in favor of constructor injection.

```
<b:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <b:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login"/>
</b:bean>
```

should be replaced with:

```
<b:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <b:constructor-arg value="/login"/>
</b:bean>
```

*Attention: there are a lot of changes in Spring Security 4 - I strongly recommend to read the complete [Migration Guid](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html)!*